# Ubuntu 19.04 Error 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80] error on apt update

Tags: ubuntu-19.04

I had uninstalled open jdk and trying to install oracle jdk8 but getting following error

```
oracle@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease       
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease             
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu eoan InRelease  
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu eoan Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Please can you help me out from this error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In software & updates app--> other softwares. Unchecked 
http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu eoan

Answer (score 12):

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:webupd8team/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Per https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/ducn4k/how_to_fix_404_not_found_ip_911899583_80

Comment: In general. the solution is to `--remove` via terminal (spartanidas answer) or uncheck via *Software Updater* (Ganesh Jadhav answer) the first PPA that is shown in the error message. And then rerun the update.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem by this:

1.First, restore the default focal repositories using these commands:

> mkdir ~/solution
> cd ~/solution/
>
> cat << EOF > ~/solution/sources.list deb
> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe
> multiverse deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main
> restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
> universe multiverse deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
> focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
> universe multiverse deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
> focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted
> universe multiverse deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
> focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner deb-src
> http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner EOF
>
> sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
> sudo cp ~/solution/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list

2.Remove all the PPAs in your system:

> sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* ~/solution

3.Update the repositories:

> sudo apt update

You can see this solution on this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385440/ubuntu-sudo-apt-get-update-404-not-found-problem

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced source.list with below text, resolved my issue.

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main
deb-src http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main


## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main
deb-src http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main


## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe


## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
# deb http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
# deb-src http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
# deb http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse


## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse


## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner


deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
```

after that run this

```
sudo apt update
```

in your terminal